# Android JNI GetMethodID() fails

Tags: java, android, c, cordova, java-native-interface

I'm trying to build a Cordova plugin to support a C library used within an Ionic Cordova app.  So far the JavaScript→Java and Java→C portions of my code work.  I can successfully debug C code from within Android Studio running on the phone.  However, my C library has a callback method that needs to be passed up the stack (C→Java→JavaScript) and I'm having issues getting the JNI methods working properly.  Here's my code so far:

**AgentMgrService.Java**

```
package com.example;

import ...

public class AgentMgrService {

    private static final String TAG = "AgentMgrService";
    private boolean libLoaded = false;
    private static Context mContext;

    public CallbackContext jsCallback;

    // C-function interface
    public static native void startAgentMgr(String agentMgrConfig);
    public static native void stopAgentMgr();

    // load library
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("lib_agentmgr");
    }
    public AgentMgrService(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void startMobileAgentMgr(String agentmgrConfig) throws RemoteException {
        startAgentMgr(agentmgrConfig);

    public void testMe() {
        Log.d(TAG, "testMe!");
    }

    public String toString() {
        Log.d(TAG, "This is a string!");
        return "This is a string!";
    }

}
```

**AgentMgrJni.c**

```
#include ...

static JavaVM* _jamgr_appVm = NULL;
static jobject _jamgr_appObj = NULL;

void
Java_com_example_AgentMgrService_startAgentMgr(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject thiz,
        jstring config_data)
{
    if (_jamgr_appObj == NULL) {
      _jamgr_appObj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, thiz);
    }

    //... Stuff happens here ...

    jni_callback();

}

int
jni_callback()
{
    JNIEnv* env = NULL;
    jint retval = 0;
    jmethodID mid = NULL;
    jclass cls = NULL;

    retval = (*_jamgr_appVm)->GetEnv(_jamgr_appVm, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, _jamgr_appObj);


    //Try the toString() method
    mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jobject strObj = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, _jamgr_appObj, mid);
    const char* str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, strObj, NULL);
    printf("\nCalling class is: %s\n", str);
    //this prints "class com.example.AgentMgrService"

    mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "testMe", "()V");
    //this returns NULL and thus the below call fails
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, _jamgr_appObj, mid, jstr);

    return retval;
}
```

When running the above code everything behaves fine until the first `GetMethodID()`.  When calling `toString()` I get the boilerplate `"class com.example.AgentMgrService"` as a reply.  But wait, I overloaded `toString()`!  Additionally, attempting to get the `testMe()` returns NULL, so it couldn't find that method.  So I'm in the right class and can in fact call some Java methods from within C, but not methods that I have defined?  I haven't tried making anything static yet but I'm unsure if that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your problem lies in whether or not your native methods are static..

In JNI, if you have

```
public static native void startAgentMgr(String agentMgrConfig);
public static native void stopAgentMgr();
```

on the java side, when you call this method, the `this` object will be a CLASS and not an INSTANCE.. After all, the method is static and it has no `this`.

However, if you change it to (Note the lack of `static` keyword):

```
public native void startAgentMgr(String agentMgrConfig);
public native void stopAgentMgr();
```

then when you run your code, `this` parameter will be the instance of the object that this method was called on.

Example:

```
package com.example.brandon.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;

public class AgentMgrService {
    private static final String TAG = "AgentMgrService";

    // load library
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("lib_agentmgr");
    }

    // C-function interface
    public native void startAgentMgr(String agentMgrConfig);
    public native void stopAgentMgr();

    public AgentMgrService(Context context) {

    }

    public void startMobileAgentMgr(String agentmgrConfig) throws RemoteException {
        startAgentMgr(agentmgrConfig);
    }

    public void testMe() {
        Log.d(TAG, "testMe!");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Log.d(TAG, "This is a string!");
        return "This is a string!";
    }
}
```

Native Code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static JavaVM* _jamgr_appVm = NULL;
static jobject _jamgr_appObj = NULL;

int jni_callback();

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* aReserved)
{
    _jamgr_appVm = vm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_brandon_test_AgentMgrService_startAgentMgr(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject thiz,
        jstring config_data)
{
    if (_jamgr_appVm == NULL)
    {
        (*env)->GetJavaVM(env, *_jamgr_appVm);
    }

    if (_jamgr_appObj == NULL) {
        _jamgr_appObj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, thiz);
    }

    jni_callback();

}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_brandon_test_AgentMgrService_stopAgentMgr(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject thiz,
        jstring config_data)
{
    (*env)->DeleteGlobalRef(env, _jamgr_appObj);
    _jamgr_appObj = NULL;
}

int jni_callback()
{
    JNIEnv* env = NULL;
    jint retval = (*_jamgr_appVm)->GetEnv(_jamgr_appVm, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);

    if (retval == JNI_OK)
    {
        jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, _jamgr_appObj);
        if (cls)
        {
            jmethodID  mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
            if (mid)
            {
                jobject strObj = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, _jamgr_appObj, mid);

                if (strObj)
                {
                    const char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, strObj, NULL);
                    printf("\nCalling class is: %s\n", str);
                    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, strObj, str);
                    strObj = NULL;
                }


                mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "testMe", "()V");

                if (mid)
                {
                    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, _jamgr_appObj, mid);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return retval;
}
```

This will do what you want because the JNI methods are NOT static on the Java side. However, if you make them static, then `getMethodID` will FAIL work because thiz is a class and not an instance of `AgentMgrJni`.

Also note that I fixed your memory leaks by `ReleasingUTFChars`.. and other error handling issues. I also called `DeleteGlobalRef` in the stop function..

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, strObj, NULL);
printf("\nCalling class is: %s\n", str);
//this prints "class com.example.AgentMgrService"
```

It prints the result of calling `_jamgr_appObj.toString()`. This is `"This is a string!"`. It is certainly *not* `"class com.example.AgentMgrService"`, and whatever it does print is certainly not the 'calling class'. Are you looking for `getClass().toString()` here?

Or else this is not the real code. Which appears far more likely.

```
//this returns NULL
```

It returns *zero.* `methodIDs` are not pointers.

```
// ... and thus the below call fails
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, _jamgr_appObj, mid, jstr);
```

Why you didn't just pass the original `thiz` object, and the `JNIEnv*`, directly to `jni_callback()` is a mystery to me. You certainly didn't need either a `GlobalRef` or to call `String.toString()`.

There is a lamentable lack of error checking in this code. *Every* JNI call must be followed by an examination of its result, and if erroneous, you must use one of the exception-checking or printing or throwing methods. Rather than proceeding as though the error didn't happen.

Comment: It certain does print `"class com.example.AgentMgrService"`, do you want me to take a screenshot of the console/debugger?

This is real, compiled code but it is a test that I am running to mimic behavior that is working correctly on a native Android application (i.e. not Ionic Cordova).  The global reference is necessary due to the way that the rest of the actual library is set up. `jni_callback()` is not called directly from the Java caller, it happens about 30 seconds later after a bunch of other worker threads are fired and do their thing.

...

Comment: ... In fact, I'm not even sure that the thread calling `jni_callback()` is the same that is being started by the Java side.  I understand that the code is bare and lacks error checking, I am merely trying to understand why I am not able to get at `AgentMgrService.testMe()` from within `jni_callback()` since it returns _zero_.  I don't really care about error checking _at the moment_ because I'm using Android Studio's debugger to step through everything.